# FastAPI on Windows 10: How to ensure data is stored in Cloud MongoDB Atlas instead of MongoDB Server?

Tags: mongodb-atlas

BACKEND ON FASTAPI, ONLY STORES DATA IN MONGODB SERVER (LOCAL), NOT IN CLOUD MONGODB ATLAS

I'm following a tutorial to build a fastapi backend and insert data in Cloud Mongodb Atlas, but all data goes stored by Mongodb Server (Local), even if it has a config file .env and MONGODB_URL addressed to the cluster database, using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10

```
configuration file:
    .env
    MONGODB_URL="mongodb+srv://eduardofernandezsv:mPINwmN7VAyJQ38X@cluster0.80m7ucn.mongodb.net/?
    retryWrites=true&w=majority"

------- utils.py
    from passlib.context import CryptContext

    pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")

    def verify_password(plain_password, hashed_password):
    return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)

    def get_password_hash(password):
    return pwd_context.hash(password)



----- main.py
    # library imports
    from fastapi import FastAPI
    from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

    # module imports
    from .routes import blog_content,users, auth, password_reset

    # initialize an app
    app = FastAPI()



    app.include_router(users.router)

----- users.py
    from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException, status
    from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
    from ..schemas import User, db, UserResponse
    from ..utils import get_password_hash
    import secrets

    router = APIRouter(
        tags=["User Routes"]
    )


    #@router.post("/registration", response_description="Register New User",
       response_model=UserResponse, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    @router.post("/registration", response_description="Register a User", response_model=UserResponse)
    async def registration(user_info: User):
    user_info = jsonable_encoder(user_info)

    # check for duplications
    username_found = await db["users"].find_one({"name": user_info["name"]})
    email_found = await db["users"].find_one({"email": user_info["email"]})

    if username_found:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT,
                            detail="There already is a user by that name")

    if email_found:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT,
                            detail="There already is a user by that email")


    # hash the user password
    user_info["password"] = get_password_hash(user_info["password"])

    # generate apiKey
    user_info["apiKey"] = secrets.token_hex(30)

    new_user = await db["users"].insert_one(user_info)
    created_user = await db["users"].find_one({"_id": new_user.inserted_id})


    # send email
    #await send_registration_mail("Registration successful", user_info["email"],
    #    {
    #        "title": "Registration successful",
    #        "name": user_info["name"]
    #    }
    #)


    return created_user

----- schemas.py
    import motor.motor_asyncio
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    from bson import ObjectId
    from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, EmailStr
    from typing import Optional
    import os

    #  load env
    load_dotenv()

    client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(os.getenv("MONGODB_URL"))

    db = client.blog_api


    #  BSON and fastapi JSON
    class PyObjectId(ObjectId):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not ObjectId.is_valid(v):
            raise ValueError("Invalid objectid")
        return ObjectId(v)

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema):
        field_schema.update(type="string") 


    class User(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId, alias="_id")
    name: str = Field(...)
    email: EmailStr = Field(...)
    password: str = Field(...)

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        json_encoders = {ObjectId: str}
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "name": "John Doe",
                "email": "jdoe@example.com",
                "password": "secret_code"
            }
        }
```

```
class UserResponse(BaseModel):
id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId, alias="_id")
name: str = Field(...)
email: EmailStr = Field(...)

class Config:
    allow_population_by_field_name = True
    arbitrary_types_allowed = True
    json_encoders = {ObjectId: str}
    schema_extra = {
        "example": {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "jdoe@example.com"
        }
    }
```

****** test_mongo_connection.py
# test file that reaches cluster database on Atlas Mongodb:
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

#  load env
load_dotenv()


cluster = MongoClient(os.getenv("MONGODB_URL"))


db = cluster["blogapi"]
collection = db["fastapi_mongo"]

collection.insert_one({"_id":0, "user_name":"Soumi"})
collection.insert_one({"_id":100, "user_name":"Ravi"})
```

```
[cloud mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGOkD.png)
[string connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0KpS.png)
[mongodb server (local)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJT8L.png)
[test to reach cloud database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ntm.png)

[running project][1]
[fastapi docs][2]
[project][3] 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFmkJ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft5Tr.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY37b.png
```